# PHP form displaying a white screen?

Tags: php, html

When I try and test my html form, it displays a white screen. Here's my code.

index.html

```
<form name="form1" method="post" action="test.php">
<textarea name="data" cols="100" rows="10">
Facebook: 
Twitter: 
Instagram:
Website: 
Comments: 
---------------------------------------------
</textarea>
<br>
<input type="submit" value="Save">
</form>
```

test.php

```
<html>
 <?php
ini_set('error_reporting', E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 'On');  //On or Off

$saving = $_REQUEST['saving'];
if ($saving == 1){ 
$data = $_POST['data'];
$file = "data.txt"; 

$fp = fopen($file, "a") or die("Couldn't open $file for writing!");
fwrite($fp, $data) or die("Couldn't write values to file!"); 

fclose($fp); 
echo "Saved to $file successfully!";
}
?>
</html>
```

I can 'view source' on the page, but I just get the code above in the php file. The title of the page is displaying the test.php page. Should it be doing this? PHP newbie. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you have a server setup?

Comment: I'm just testing it though dreamweaver. Should I upload it to my website and try it? @LuckySoni

Comment: @KyleKoogler Your website won't display changes in your code until you upload it...

Comment: I uploaded it, it does the same thing. Nothing but a nice white screen with no input to my .txt file. @Rottingham

Comment: add this before the final ?> tag : var_dump($_POST); See if your form is actually getting any values.

Comment: array(2) { ["data"]=> string(112) "Facebook: f Twitter: f Instagram:ff Website: f Comments: ff --------------------------------------------- " ["saving"]=> string(4) "Save" } -- that was the output I got

Comment: Edit your question with the new test.php file contents. You shouldn't have the $saving item anymore

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Give this a try, tested. (no white screen)

Use both bodies of code as written.

I added a condition in case someone tries to access `test.php` directly.

### HTML form

```
<form name="form1" method="post" action="test.php">
<textarea name="data" cols="100" rows="10">
Facebook: 
Twitter: 
Instagram: 
Website: 
Comments: 
---------------------------------------------
</textarea>
<br>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Save">
</form>
```

### PHP hander (test.php)

```
<html>
<?php
ini_set('error_reporting', E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 'On');  //On or Off

if(!isset($_REQUEST['data'])) {
echo "You cannot do that from here.";
exit;
}

else {
$data = $_REQUEST['data'];
}

if(isset($_REQUEST['submit'])) {
$file = "data.txt";
chmod($file, 0777);
// chmod($file, 0644); // or use 644 which is safer

$fp = fopen($file, "a") or die("Couldn't open $file for writing!");
fwrite($fp, $data) or die("Couldn't write values to file!"); 

fclose($fp); 
echo "Saved to $file successfully!";
}

else {

echo "Submit not set.";
}

?>
</html>
```

Comment: I got the "Submit not set." @Fred -ii-

Comment: @KyleKoogler Ok, totally baffled here. I tested this and it worked 100% otherwise I wouldn't have given it. Now, you copied my NEW FORM and not yours and uploaded to your server and reloaded the page? Cuz that's the big difference here. I am next to certain that you didn't use the form code I put here and that's why you got that error message because your form does not have a name to your submit button.

Comment: @KyleKoogler and you cleared your cache? I'm using FF 23.0.1 and not a hitch. Like I said, I didn't test this 99%, I tested it 100%, in every which way possible. I am "thorough" with my work.

Comment: @KyleKooger Did you make sure to upload your changes as well?

Comment: @Rottingham I take it that you agree with me that my example works.

Comment: I'm just having trouble getting input to show up on data.txt. I'm sure it's something stupid, and you guys have been a big help. @Fred-ii-

Comment: @KyleKoogler Ok well then, try chmod'ing the file to either `644` first or `777` after. Might be a permissions thing.

Comment: Like I said, newbie. Three days on PHP max. Mind explaining this? @Fred-ii-

Comment: @KyleKoogler Servers act differently sometimes. A "permission" is the amount of permission a file is given in order to have data written to it, or given access to view it. I will edit my answer with `chmod($file, 0644);` inside it and `chmod($file, 0777);` Give me a minute, I'll let you know when I'm done and you can try it again after with the updated code.

Comment: @KyleKoogler Ok, reload my answer and copy the new handler code and upload to your server and try it again, see what that does.

Comment: @KyleKoogler You're welcome. You can accept my answer with **clicking the checkmark** under the arrows until it turns **green.** It's better than an upvote ;-) plus your question won't remain in the unanswered category.

Comment: @KyleKoogler See my comment above this one on how to rep me up. Since it did solve your problem.

Comment: @Rottingham Thanks, same for you too. Will `+1` you. I knew we'd find the culprit. File permissions is what it was but other factors too that stood in the way. Cheers ;-)

Comment: @KyleKoogler Have a look at what PHP.net explains on chmod in case you would like to know the specifics on it: http://php.net/manual/en/function.chmod.php (better than I have explained already). Glad we were able to solve your problem, cheers :)

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you are getting into the if code

```
$saving = $_REQUEST['saving'];
if ($saving == 1) { 
    $data = $_POST['data'];
    $file = "data.txt"; 
    $fp = fopen($file, "a") or die("Couldn't open $file for writing!");
    fwrite($fp, $data) or die("Couldn't write values to file!"); 

    fclose($fp); 
    echo "Saved to $file successfully!";
} else {
    echo 'Nope!';
}
```

Try adding this ELSE and see if you see 'Nope'.

For starters, what is $_REQUEST['saving']? It isn't an input on the form so it is probably a nothing.

Do this instead:

```
if ($_POST) { 
    $data = $_POST['data'];
    $file = "data.txt"; 
    $fp = fopen($file, "a") or die("Couldn't open $file for writing!");
    fwrite($fp, $data) or die("Couldn't write values to file!"); 

    fclose($fp); 
    echo "Saved to $file successfully!";
} else {
    echo 'Nope!';
}
```

Comment: It would be best to use the if ($_POST) check so that the file doesn't get executed unless a form is actually submitted.

Comment: I'm still getting the white screen that shows absolutely nothing. I also tried the else, it did not display anything. @Rottingham

Comment: @KyleKoogler Rottingham's idea/example works because I just tested it now, so there's something on your end that's not happening here.

Answer (score 0):

Change your html:

```
<input type="submit" value="Save" name="saving"/>
```

Also change the php where you are accepting the param:

```
$saving = $_REQUEST['saving'];
if ($saving) { // it is enough to just check if there is a value, the actual value is "Save"
    ...
}
```